# development practices for jira

Tags: git, jira, development-environment

we are going to set up jira,  we can just put it in the server, and give every one the link,  but my team is going to add custom fields, scripted fields and we are going to modify the workflow,    do we have to do this in the production jira instance?

or can each developer have a local jira, jira sdk,  modify the workflow and push it with git to the server?  or this is something that only works for developing plugins,   most of the things we are going to be working is modifying the workflow and adding fields, maybe a couple of scripted fields.

thanks guys  we appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your need and team size, you may want to consider [Atlassian's recommended strategy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/establishing-staging-server-environments-for-jira-720411697.html).
basically it involves setting up three JIRA instances: develop, stage, and production.

- Use the development server to perform and test your modifications, as
  well as test new JIRA versions, plug-ins, etc.
- Use the staging server to apply and test specific changes on a copy of the production database.
- Then, when confirmed OK, re-apply the changes on the production server.

Note, there is no 'source control' for JIRA. In some cases (such as workflow changes), you can apply the changes by exporting and importing. But things like adding custom fields or modifying scripted fields, require re-doing the operation again in each tier (either manually, or by scripting e.g. using the REST API).

By the way, in my workplace we decided to settle for 2 tiers, since only a couple of people make modifications to JIRA, and each change is authorized by a triage (R&D leader, QA leader, and CM leader) before applying to production.

Comment: can the 3 instances run in the same server? do we need to pay for each one?  thanks =)

Comment: You can run them on the same server, but performance will be greatly reduced (JIRA is very memory-hungry). As for paying, you need a separate license per instance. But in most cases, you can settle for the 'beginner' license (10$ per year) in the dev and stage instances, so it's hardly a concern.